# Does anybody know how to use the RESTful API of OpenRailway (from Openstreetmap)?

Tags: rest, openstreetmap

Does anybody know how to use the RESTful API of OpenRailway (from Openstreetmap)?

It is mentioned on their website, but does not seem to be documented: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap/API

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [source](https://github.com/rurseekatze/OpenRailwayMap/zipball/master) for their server setup. There don't appear to be all that many API calls, but that's as good a place as any to start. The API functions are in /api and are implemented in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get Data from the API. But I found https://overpass-turbo.eu/
where you can export Data of a visible Map section. If you type this, you can export Stations, Signals Switches ... as XML Data - GeoJSON, GPX, KML, OSM data ...

```
node
  [railway]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

If you only want the stations, type

```
node
  [railway=station]
  ({{bbox}});
out;
```

Have fun.